# Front-end Profile View Issues

Tags: wordpress, profile

I feel like I've run into these issues before but for the life of me cannot remember the solution.

I have a front-end profile listing, when you go to view the full profile, all the fields are clickable but the actions after the click are inconsistent. For example:

Click on a website URL - goes to the website
Click on an email link - goes back to the profile list search results for that email address.
Click on a custom field (note type) - goes back to the profile list search results for that field.

Obviously, the problem with the Bio field is the worst, and even though the field is set to NOT be searchable, you're able to click on it and search by it. Setting it to View Only didn't do anything.

Wordpress 4.3x
CiviCRM 4.6.10

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not allowed to comment (what's up with that?), I'll ask for clarification here.

1. What results are you expecting for each type?
2. What do you mean by the 'Bio' field? Can you post a link?

Comment: I believe you need to have a reputation score of at least 50 to comment. Looks like yours is currently sitting at 41.  I thought I had put the link in there. Here it is.
http://www.leadsgroup-4.com/members-of-leads-group-4/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/view&reset=1&id=2&gid=15

Comment: Bumped your "answer" - you should have 51 now :-)