# Clicking Fields in Front-end Profile View Gives Inconsistent Results

Tags: wordpress, profile, search

These issues have existed for a while, but perhaps without resolution?

[Front-end Profile View Issues](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/front-end-profile-view-issues)

When you go to view the full profile from a profile-based search, all the fields are clickable but the actions after the click are inconsistent. For example:

Click on a website URL - goes to the website. Click on an email link - goes back to the profile list search results for that email address. Click on a text-type field - adds that to the search criteria.

I would rather have email fields trigger an "emailto:" type action.

And in the specific instance I'm working with, it would probably be best if text type fields were not clickable at all in the full profile.

All profile fields are set to `Expose publicly and for listings`.

Wordpress 4.7.5 CiviCRM 4.7.17

Comment: The example you link to isn't publicly accessible - perhaps that site needs an ACL or to allow anonymous users to view profiles?

Comment: Sorry about that. Eliminating site for now. Will try to fix later.

Comment: Thanks, Jon G, corrected permissions and "Expose publicly" and all is well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you setup your fields set visibility to "Public Pages". Otherwise in the detailed view the data will show as a link which when clicked will re-run the search based on that value.

Websites are turned into a hyperlink by default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All fields are set to "Expose publicly and for listings".  Is this correct?  There is also an "Expose pubicly" option.

Comment: If you set them to expose publicly they should not show as a hyperlink (which resets the search) unless it is a website which will link to the website.