# Allowing users to update information without logging in

Tags: profile

I have now followed all the instructions in the CiviCRM Cookbook (https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/civicrm-cookbook) as well as a similar post here on Stack ([allow anonymous users to view profiles in WordPress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/allow-anonymous-users-to-view-profiles-in-wordpress/18738)) but had no joy getting the URL right to get people to update their profile without having to log in.

The instructions state the following:

Using the CiviCRM checksum token in combination with a profile allows you to bypass the requirement to log in.

1. Create a profile you wish to use. The profile contains all the fields of information that
   you want the user to complete.
2. Make a note of the profile ID.
3. Enable Profile Listings and Forms access for anonymous and authenticated users
   in your CMS.
4. Now create a CiviMail mailing in the normal way.
5. You now need to use the {contact.checksum} token and the {contact.
   contact_id} token to construct a link back to edit the profile you created:
   http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/profile/
   edit?reset=1&gid=N&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
6. Substitute your website for http://www.myorganization.org.

Perhaps there was a print error in the book because I have tried numerous variable options to get this working without joy.

Any thoughts? Thanks

EDIT: Added example below.

https://crm.example.com/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=1&id=2798&5fb7dfc93d6b855d75659da64805ac82_1503574955_179

Comment: the construction differs depending on your cms. best info imo is at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/framework/civimail/tokens/   why not paste what you constructed (without your domain if that needs to be kept private). Also check your permissions that anon have access to Custom Fields etc.

Comment: Thanks @petednz-fuzion. I have added the example URL. Also, the Custom Fields is allowed too. I don't think the subdomain or the SSL certificate should affect this right? I would expect a variable name for the checksum but the instructions are unclear what that var should be.

Comment: `{contact.checksum}` should expand to `cs=XXX`  Your example does not include `cs=`.  Was that a copying error or is that how it really is?  What version are you running?  You could try manually adding the `cs=` but it should be included automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The construction differs depending on your cms.

Best info imo is at docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/framework/civimail/tokens

You have pasted

civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=1&id=2798&5fb7dfc93d6b855d75659da64805ac82_1503574955_179

In point 5. you stated ** and the {contact. contact_id}** but i don't see that in your example.

You need to have **cid={contact. contact_id}** in the string so will not work

Answer (score 1):

As Pete says, your question (and Stack Exchange history) suggests you're using WordPress - but the example you added is using the Drupal URL construction.

In addition to Pete's answer, there's also the [Fancy Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens) extension, which you can install from the in-app Extensions directory.  It takes the pain out of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to allow user to update their profile without logging in:

```
http://www.myorganization.org/mybasepage?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=2&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
```

Please note that:

- www.myorganization.org is the URL where CiviCRM is installed
- mybasepage is the basepage of your CiviCRM installation (usually it's civicrm, but it may vary)
- gid=2 is the profile ID number

(Found this solution [here](https://aghstrategies.com/content/how-create-one-click-personalized-links-civicrm-emails))